# Is there a neat way to organize uni-conditional code that exists at different sections of a program?

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, code-organization

For example, I'd like to have something like this:

```
If(condition) object.start();

// Do some unrelated processing

If(condition) object.stop();
```

As a simple example of what I would like to happen. Are there any language agnostic ways to organize this, especially as you have more conditional lines of code?

Comment: i don't really get what you want.. a while loop? a switch-case statement?

Comment: Gewure, I'd like to know if there's a way to execute code in different parts of a program that is based on the same condition without repeating the same if conditional before each line.

Comment: sure, 'encapsulate' it in a function whichs operates on a status-variable.

e.g.: `def bla():  if(statusVar == 1): doSomething() else: return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're asking this because the condition is expensive or non-repeatable.

One typical solution would be to set a boolean variable in the first IF, and let the second IF check that boolean variable instead of re-executing the condition.

```
boolVar=false
if (condition) {
  boolVar=true
  object.start()
}
// do unrelated stuff
if (boolVar) {
  object.stop()
}
```

Another typical solution would be something like this :

```
if (condition) {
  object.start()
  doSomething()
  object.end()
} else {
  doSomething()
}
```

Don't be afraid of simple solutions, if they're good enough. :)